# what wrong with my testing2.php

Tags: php, forms

here is my php form code...

```
 <?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Page Title Goes Here</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form1.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

            // define variables and set to empty value
            $firstNameError = "";
            $lastNameError = "";
            $error = false;

            // if firstName is empty, make it NULL, else, test_input() the data.
            $firstName = empty($_POST["firstName"]) ? NULL : test_input($_POST["firstName"]);

            // if lastName is empty, make it NULL, else, test_input() the data.
            $lastName = empty($_POST["lastName"]) ? NULL : test_input($_POST["lastName"]);

            if (isset($_POST["submittingForm"])) {

                /// CHECK FIRST NAME ERRORS
                if ($firstName === NULL) {
                    // firstName is empty
                    $firstNameError = "First name is required!";
                    $error = true;

                } else {
                    // check characters
                    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $firstName)) {
                        $firstNameError = "Only letters and white spaces allowed!";
                        $error = true;
                    }
                }

                /// CHECK LAST NAME ERRORS
                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $lastName)) {
                    // check characters
                    $lastNameError = "Only letters and white spaces allowed!";
                    $error = true;
                }

                // if no error then redirect
                if (!$error) {
                    $_SESSION['fistName'] = $firstName;
                    $_SESSION['lastName'] = $lastName;
                    header('Location: testing2.php');
                    exit();
                }

            } else {
                // user did not submit form!
            }

            // clean input
            function test_input($data) {
                $data = trim($data);
                $data = stripslashes($data);
                $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                return $data;
            }

        ?>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <h1>Welcome to Chollerton Tearoom! </h1>
            <form id="userdetail" method="POST">
                <fieldset id="aboutyou">
                    <legend id="legendauto">user information</legend>
                    <p>
                        <label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="<?php echo $firstName; ?>">
                        <span class="error">* <?php echo $firstNameError;?></span>

                        <label for="lastName">Last Name: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value="<?php echo $lastName; ?>">
                        <span class="error">* <?php echo $lastNameError;?></span>
                    </p>
                    <p> 
                        <input type="submit" name="submittingForm" value="submit">
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and so here is my testing2.php which get the data after submited...

```
    <?php 

session_start();

$firstName = $_SESSION['firstName'];
$lastName = $_SESSION['lastName'];


echo "<h1>Successfull submission :</h1>";
echo "<p>fitstName :  $firstName <p/>";
echo "<p>lastName :  $lastName <p/>";
?>
```

when the form is submited , Notice: Undefined index: firstName in F:\xampp\htdocs\en407b\assigment\testing2.php on line 5 is appear...
i've tried to fix it but still cnt get it right...
pls help me....

Comment: and also....
the lastname suppose to auto assign to null if it is not filled it....
after submited , there is a black in the testing2.php...
Successfull submission :

fitstName : asdsada

lastName :

how to fix it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change like this

```
    if (!$error) {
                $_SESSION['firstName'] = $firstName;//error here
                $_SESSION['lastName'] = $lastName;
                header('Location: testing2.php');
                exit();
            }
```

Comment: sir...
the lastName did not auto assign the word "NULL" in the testing2.php page if lastName is empty...
how can i fix it?

Comment: change echo "<p>lastName :  $lastName <p/>"; in testing2.php   to                                       if($_SESSION['lastName']==NULL){echo "firstName:NULL";} else {echo "<p>lastName :  $lastName <p/>";}

Comment: this is simple method

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple typo -

```
if (!$error) {
    $_SESSION['fistName'] = $firstName;
```

should be:

```
if (!$error) {
    $_SESSION['firstName'] = $firstName;
```

I'd also recommend giving your form an action:

```
<form id="userdetail" action="testing2.php" method="POST">
```

and then move all the form processing logic over into that file. That would eliminate the need for a header redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in your session name. You are assigning session to `$_SESSION['fistName']` and trying to access it with `$_SESSION['firstName'];`

Comment: sir... the lastName did not auto assign the word "NULL" in the testing2.php page if lastName is empty... how can i fix it?